# Show that if $B\subset A$ then $\mu(A)=\mu(B) \iff \mu(A \cap T)=\mu(B \cap T)$ for all measurable sets $T$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a measure on $\mathbb{R}^{N}, B \subset A \subset \mathbb{R}^{N}$ with a $\mu$-measurable set $ A $ with finite measure $\mu(A)<\infty$. Show that
$$\mu(A)=\mu(B) \iff\mu(A \cap T)=\mu(B \cap T)$$ for all measurable sets $ T \subset \mathbb{R}^{N}$.

I can't figure out how to show this - theoretically I know the following:
$A \subset \mathbb{R}^{N}$ is called $\mu$-cap of $B \subset A$ if $A$ $\mu$-measurable, $B \subset A$ and $\mu(T \cap A)=\mu(T \cap B)$ is valid for all measurable $T \subset \mathbb{R}^{N}$

In the case of $\mu(B)<\infty$, $A$ $\mu$-measurable, $A \subset B$ and for all measurable $ T \subset \mathbb{R}^{N}$ applies:
$$
\mu(A)=\mu(B) \iff \mu(T \cap A)=\mu(T \cap B)$$

Comment: 1. Please do not make titles that consist only of MathJax code; they break some navigational shortcuts. 2. Please don't put unnecessary white space in titles. 3. `\iff` produces a longer "fat" arrow with some additional (but not nearly as excessive) white space around it: `A\iff B` produces $A\iff B$, versus `A\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad B`: $A\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad B$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks for the hint - but how should I make my question titles more useful?

Comment: I didn't say anything about "useful"; my comments were about formatting.

Comment: $T$ is not a quantity, it's a set.

Comment: The statement in the title is clearly false. Omitting a crucial hypothesis leads to confusion. Perhaps the title should be a bit less built on mathematical equivalencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm somewhat suspicious because I never used that $A\subset \mathbb R^n$, but I cannot find an error in my approach so I'm posting here. I assume $B$ is measurable because you write $\mu (B)$. The left direction ($\Leftarrow$) is trivial by taking $T=B$.

For $\Rightarrow)$, assume $B\subset A$, $\mu(B)=\mu(A)$ and $T$ is measurable. We want $\mu(A\cap T)=\mu(B\cap T)$.

The only thing we know about $A$ is that it's a superset of $B$, so we can think in two directions:

1. take out the $B$ part of $A$ into its own "summand" in a disjoint union $A=B\cup (A\setminus B)$ in hope to expand the left-hand side in the target equality to something that includes (subsumes) the right-hand side;
2. note that if a set lies within another and has the same measure, then the difference must be a null set: $\mu (A\setminus B)=0$ (why?).

I'll hide the rest behind a spoiler because I still think it's fun to try it yourself with the above hints.

> By the first note $$\begin{align}A\cap T&=\left(B\cup(A\setminus B)\right)\cap T\\&=\left(B\cap T\right)\cup\left((A\setminus B)\cap T\right)\end{align}$$ is still a disjoint union, hence $$\mu(A\cap T)=\mu(B\cap T)+\mu((A\setminus B)\cap T),$$ and by the second note, the second summand is zero (why?). Therefore, $\mu(A\cap T)=\mu(B\cap T)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and explanation. I aslo haven't had A⊂R^n in this context before - but your proof is very comprehensible and I think it will fit anyway.