# For sets $B$ with $μ(B)<∞$ the existence of an $μ$-hull follows from the Borel regularity of the measure $μ$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, borel-measures

[From this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4800020/show-that-if-b-subset-a-then-mua-mub-iff-mua-cap-t-mub-cap-t) I should also be able to conclude that for sets $B$ with $\mu(B)<\infty$ the existence of an $\mu$-hull follows from the Borel regularity of the measure $\mu $:

I know:

> An outer measure $\mu$ is called Borel measure if all open and thus
> all Borel sets $\mu$-are measurable. $\mu$ is called Borel-regular if
> in addition each subset $A \subset \mathbb{R}^{N}$ has a Borel
> superset $B$ with the same measure. $\mu$ is called open-regular if
> $B$ in the case $\mu(A)<\infty$.

$A \subset \mathbb{R}^{N}$ is so called $\mu$-hull of $B \subset A$ if $A \mu$-measurable, $B \subset A$ and $\mu(T \cap A)=\mu(T \cap B)$ applies to all measurable $T \subset \mathbb{R}^{N}$

But how do I show $\mu(T \cap A)=\mu(T \cap B)$ (or is this analogue to the proof of the question linked above)?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by $\mu$-cover?

Comment: I have probably made a translation error - I mean the following:
$A \subset \mathbb{R}^{N}$ is so called $\mu$-hull of $B \subset A$ if $A \mu$-measurable, $B \subset A$ and $\mu(T \cap A)=\mu(T \cap B)$ applies to all measurable $T \subset \mathbb{R}^{N}$

Comment: It is unclear what you want to show. Are you assuming that $\mu(B)$ is defined and you want to find such an $A$? Why not simply take $A=B$?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur: for sets B with μ(B)<∞ the existence of an μ-hull follows from the Borel regularity of the measure μ.
Related to the question I linked to above

Comment: I think I am missing something. Why is every set not the $\mu$-hull of itself?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur: Why is every set not the μ
-hull of itself? - good question?????